# Set theory, intersection and union between $n$ sets $A_1 ⊆ A_2\ldots ⊆ A_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have $n$ sets $A_1, A_2\ldots A_n$ and also I know $A_1 ⊆ A_2\ldots ⊆ A_n.$
I need to prove 2 things (in the picture)
[image]
I tried to do it by induction but my teacher said he doesn't want me to prove by induction (I need to stick to definitions of union and intersection).
I tried to put bracket between the sets and claim that the place of a bracket doesn't damage the unions and the intersections.
Do you think it will be enough ? If you have another idea, I will be glad to get some help.

Comment: You should note you're actually talking about _sets_, not groups. Wouldn't matter except that "group" has a specific different meaning...

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $A_n\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$. On the other hand, if $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$, then $x\in A_i$, for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. But $A_i\subset A_n$, and therefore $x\in A_n$. So $A_n\supset\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$.

Can you deal with the other equality now?

Answer (score 1):

Double inclusion...

If $x \in \bigcup A_i$ then $x \in A_j$, for some $1 \le j \le n$. And thus $x \in A_n$.

Conversly, if $x \in A_n$ then $x \in \bigcup A_i$.

---

If $x \in \bigcap A_i$ then $x \in A_j$, for every $1 \le j \le n$, and thus also $x \in A_1$.

And if $x \in A_1$, then...

Comment: I am sorry. Are we using the fact that $A_j\subseteq A_n$ for all $j\in [0,n]$? Wondering if need induction principle for that.